# What is meant by Expectation or Expected value of a Random Variable?

Tags: probability, expectation

Probability: In terms of Relative frequency.

$S$: Sample Space of an experiment

$E$: Experiment performed.

For each event $E$ of sample space $S$, we define $n(E)$ : no. of times in first $n$ repetitions of the experiment that the event $E$ occurs.

$P(E) = \lim_{n \to \infty} \frac{n(E)}{n}$

It is the proportion of time that Event $E$ occurs.

Is it correct to say that perform the experiment first and then calculate the probable chances of event $E$ to occur depending on the output of our experiment?

Expectation:(What i read from text book) If $X$ is a random variable having a probability mass function $p(x)$ , then expected value of $X$ is:

$E[X] = \sum_{x:p(x)>0}^{}xp(x)$.

What the expectation value of X is describing for X just like probability is describing the proportion of time event $E$ occurs.

$e.g$  $E[X :$ outcome when roll a fair die$]$ = 7/2.
What the 7/2 or 3.5 value signifies?

I am confused between these two. I understand the probability concept but not expectation. It is better if explains using some example?

Comment: I'm not sure I fully understand what you're asking, but the relationship between the two concepts you're talking about is called the law of large numbers. It's a theorem which is not particularly obvious.

Comment: I am asking about what the expectation is defining for the random variable. e.g Probability of getting even number in rolling a fair dice is 1/2 which is same as probability of getting odd number but the expectation of getting even number is 2 which is not same as 1.5(For odd number). What these numbers signifies about the outcome of rolling the dice. Does it means that occurrence of even numbers is more likely to occur is dice is rolled or something else?

Comment: Maybe your difficulties stem from using the same letter $E$ for "experiment", "event", and "expectation".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you roll a fair die, there are six possible outcomes, $1,2,3,4,5,6$, which are equally likely. The average of these six numbers $(1+2+3+4+5+6)/6 = 7/2$. We might say that "on average", if you roll a die, the outcome should be $7/2$. That is of course absurd for a single die roll, but it becomes increasingly true of the *sample mean* (i.e., the sum of the rolled values, divided by the number of rolls) if we perform more rolls.

To express this mathematically, suppose we roll the die $N$ times, and call the $n$'th outcome $x_n$, (so $x_n$ is one of $1,2,3,4,5,6$) and compute the sample mean of the $N$ resulting numbers:

$$\frac{1}{N}\sum_{n=1}^{N}x_n$$

we expect the result to be near $3.5$ if $N$ is large.

This can be quantified more precisely by the [law of large numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_large_numbers), which says (stated informally) that the sample mean is increasingly likely to be close to the expected value, as $N$ grows large, and in fact the probability that the sample mean differs from the expected value approaches zero as $N \to \infty$.

**Edited** to respond to the comment by the OP:

Let's consider rolling the die $2$ times. There are $36$ possible outcomes, as follows:

$$\begin{aligned}
(1,1)\qquad(2,1)\qquad(3,1)\qquad(4,1)\qquad(5,1)\qquad(6,1) \\
(1,2)\qquad(2,2)\qquad(3,2)\qquad(4,2)\qquad(5,2)\qquad(6,2) \\
(1,3)\qquad(2,3)\qquad(3,3)\qquad(4,3)\qquad(5,3)\qquad(6,3) \\
(1,4)\qquad(2,4)\qquad(3,4)\qquad(4,4)\qquad(5,4)\qquad(6,4) \\
(1,5)\qquad(2,5)\qquad(3,5)\qquad(4,5)\qquad(5,5)\qquad(6,5) \\
(1,6)\qquad(2,6)\qquad(3,6)\qquad(4,6)\qquad(5,6)\qquad(6,6) \\
\end{aligned}$$
Each outcome is equally likely, with probability $1/36$. Now let's look at the *sample mean* of the two rolls in each case. So for example, for the first outcome, both rolls were $1$, so the sample mean is $(1+1)/2 = 1$. Computing the sample mean for all $36$ outcomes:
$$\begin{aligned}
1\qquad 1.5\qquad 2\qquad 2.5\qquad 3\qquad 3.5 \\
1.5\qquad 2\qquad 2.5\qquad 3\qquad 3.5\qquad 4 \\
2\qquad 2.5\qquad 3\qquad 3.5\qquad 4\qquad 4.5 \\
2.5\qquad 3\qquad 3.5\qquad 4\qquad 4.5\qquad 5 \\
3\qquad 3.5\qquad 4\qquad 4.5\qquad 5\qquad 5.5 \\
3.5\qquad 4\qquad 4.5\qquad 5\qquad 5.5\qquad 6 \\
\end{aligned}$$
Notice that some sample mean values are more likely than others.

For example, there is only one outcome, namely $(1,1)$, which results in a sample mean of $1$, and similarly, only $(6,6)$ gives a sample mean of $6$. So the probability of observing a sample mean of $1$ is only $1/36$, and similarly for a sample mean of $6$.

On the other hand, there are three outcomes that give a sample mean of $2$, namely $(3,1)$, $(2,2)$, and $(1,3)$. So the probability of observing a sample mean of $2$ is $3/36 = 1/12$.

Looking at the second table, the most likely observed sample mean is $3.5$. It occurs once in each row, for a total of $6$ out of $36$, so the probability that the sample mean is $3.5$ is $1/6$.

If we were to repeat the experiment with more rolls, we would see that a higher percentage of outcomes would result in sample means near $3.5$, and this percentage would grow closer and closer to $100\%$ as the number of rolls grows larger and larger.

Comment: "we expect the result to be near 3.5 if N is large": What i understand from this is that we are expecting the that every time we roll a die, there should be different number to come and also there should be no continuously repeating some values again and again .Ideally we are expecting n different numbers in each of the n rolls and then repeat the same for next n rolls(N = m*n). Is it correct?

Comment: @Sanjeev: The die does not have any memory. Each time you roll it, there is $1/6$ probability of each outcome $1,2,3,4,5,6$. So it is *not* correct to say "there should be a different number to come and there should be no continuously repeating some values again and again." Repeats are certainly possible, with some probability. Anyway, this has nothing to do with the expected value of the roll.

Comment: Thank you. Explaining by example makes my life easier.

Comment: Does that mean expected value is the most probable value?

Answer (score 0):

The two concepts are very different. The first one, $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n(E)}{n}$ is a random variable, so it is a map from the probability space to the reals. The second one, the expectation $\mathbb{E}[X]$, is a real number, not a map.

To see the connection, we need to define the random variable $X=1_{E}$, which is the indicator function of the event $E$. In this case, the expectation $\mathbb{E}[X]=\mathbb{P}(E)$ is the probability of the set $E$. On the other hand, the strong law of large numbers tells us that the limit of the random variables $\frac{n(E)}{n}$ as $n\to\infty$ is a (almost surely) constant random variable taking the value $\mathbb{P}(E)$ with probability one.

So, the limit of the relative occurrences is a map which almost surely takes the value $\mathbb{P}(E)$, the expectation of $1_E$ is exactly that value.

The limit of the relative occurrences models an infinitely repeated experiment which approximates the probability of $E$. It is a map, because depending on how the experiment goes, we get a result. The expectation of $1_{E}$ is just the probability of $E$. In the von Mises interpretation of what a probability is, they exactly use this relation provided by the strong law of large numbers. The interpretation says that we should think of the probability of an event as the result of such an infinitely often, independently repeated experiment as described by $\lim_{n\to\infty} \frac{n(E)}{n}$.